# How to format the TextInput component value in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, textinput

I use this function to format every number input I have :

```
export const parseToNumber = (value: string) => {
  const numberRegex = /^[0-9\b]+$/;

  if (numberRegex.test(value)) {
    return value;
  } else {
    return value.replace(/\D/g, "");
  }
};
```

And I use it with another function to have a an empty space between every 4 characters  like this :

```
  onChangeText={(e) => {
                        setFieldValue(
                          "phone",
                          parseToNumber(e).replace(/(.{4})/g, "$1  ")
                        );
                      }}
```

[image]

The problem is the `Backspace` won't work because of the `parseToNumber` . How can I exclude the functions when the user presses the `Backspace` and use the simple way like this `setFieldValue("phone", (e));` so the backspace works ?

Or is there another way to fix the `Backspace` disabled problem with these functions in place possibly modify the `parseToNumber` function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Problem is parseToNumber, you can make sure only take numbers by opening numbers only keyboard by passing prop

```
  keyboardType = 'numeric'
```

or to simplify the use and support multiple spacing for input you can use this library - *react-native-mask-input*, its js only library so you can also just copy the specific implementation on need to use basis.